# haskell - parsing/reading content of .pdf-files

Tags: parsing, pdf, haskell, ghc, pdf-parsing

is there any possibility in haskell to just decrypt a .pdf file, read in the content and return a String?
And, if there is one, could you give me a little example like e.g.:

```
...
import necessaryPackage
...
pdfParsing = ...
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards, Jimmy

Answer (score 8):

- [Pdf2line](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pdf2line)
- Dylanmc's PDF lib [might also work](https://github.com/dylanmc/Haskell-PDF-Parsing-Library/blob/master/PDFLibrary.cabal)